# Sending bitcoins with armoryd fails

Tags: armory

What is the correct process to send bitcoins using only armoryd? I'm using Armory 0.93.3 on MacOs Sierra.

I have Bitcoin Core 0.14.1 and another instance of armoryd running and up to date.
Here's what I figured out so far:

```
$ ./armoryd getarmorydinfo
{
     ...
     "versionstr": "0.93.3",
     ...
}
$ ./armoryd createustxtoaddress <address> 0.001 0.0001 > test.txt
$ cat test.txt
=====TXSIGCOLLECT-XxXxXxXx======================================
...
$ ./armoryd walletpassphrase <passphrase> 100
Wallet XXXXXXX has been unlocked.
$ ./armoryd signasciitransaction test.txt > test.txt.sig
$ cat test.txt.sig
=====TXSIGCOLLECT-XxXxXxXx======================================
...
$ ./armoryd sendasciitransaction test.txt.sig
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

However, the transaction doesn't show up on blockexplorers. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use Bitcoin Core 0.14.0+ with Armory, you need to have Armory 0.96. Since you are using Armory 0.93.3, you will need to use Bitcoin Core 0.13.2 or earlier. Also keep in mind the armoryd has not been maintained for the past couple of versions so it may not work if you use Armory 0.94+.